# Is there anyway to copy multiples rows/groups in the SSRS editor/XML?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm editing a rather long and heavy report that was made by someone else.

I need to add new sections that are quite similar to already existing ones, so I tried to just copy and edit what I needed... But it doesn't seems to work in the editor.

I also tried making a copy of the `TablixRow` from the XML (code edit). But after that, the display was working (I was seeing my new rows in the design view), but VS2k8 would crash after a few seconds...

So I thought, maybe there's something I didn't see, or maybe I need to change something in the XML after the copy...

Comment: Your question is currently too general for me to provide any input on.  What didn't "seem to work"?  Did you receive an error?

Comment: Right click on a row -> no "copy option", there's one in the 'edit menu', but it won't copy to clipboard. Same if I try it on a "line group". I'm trying to copy rows/groups to not have to redefine them from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be : 'No'.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to copy a row, I believe the best way is to insert a new row, delete (if needed) its cells and then you can copy cells from the original row (the cells you can multiselect)

All of that using GUI editor, without touching raw XML code.

Comment: It works well for cell contents, but what about groups definition?

Comment: Might need to do the same, create a new group and copy/paste original group definition.